# How to declare an array in a function and call the function in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an assignment and I cannot figure out this part.

The assignment requires that I create two separate functions and call them in the main.  So my question is what is the syntax for calling a pointer to an array and how do I call that function in the main program?  For example,

```
int function_1(int x, *array);
```

How would I call `function_1`?  Or am I completely lost here?

I should add that anytime I try and call the function with the array, I get this error:
`[Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`

Comment: You can simply google this "C functions". It seems to me that no research whatsoever was done.

Answer (score 1):

```
int function(int x, char *array)
{
     //do some work
     return 0;
}
```

And in main

```
int main()
{
    char arr[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    int x = 5;
    function(x, &arr[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly enough, arrays are already pointers in C. So if you want to pass an array as a pointer to your function, you just simply pass the array you declared! I gave a little example below, although, I don't know what your code is supposed to do. I passed `function_1(...)` the number 12, and then the array pointer.

```
int function_1(int x, *array)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
  //declare a ten element integer array
  int arr[10];

  //calls the function, passing in 12 for the integer, and a pointer to the array.
  function_1(12, arr);

  ...

  return 0;
}
```

I hope this clears it up a little. The method of using the square brackets with arrays `[]` is actually something you can do with all pointers in C.You don't really need to consider that part too much yet, but just remember that arrays are already pointers, so you don't need to do anything else to pass them as pointers. In fact, you could rewrite your function to just use an array as an argument, like this, rather than using a `*` for pointers:

```
int function_1(int x, int array[])
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Arrays and pointers are different. It's just that arrays easily decay into pointers.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, thanks. You don't have to pass them by reference to modify the array contents in a function though, correct?

Comment: The normal way you access the data in an array from a different function is that you pass by value a pointer to the array. You normally write this as `function_1(15, arr)` because in that context (and many others) the array `arr` will decay into a pointer.